# Serializer for interface / implementation

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.serialization

Suppose there is one interface , and 2 (or more) implementations :

```
interface IRunnable {
  fun run()
}

class Horse : IRunnable {
  override fun run() {    println("horse running")  }
}

class Dog : IRunnable {
  override fun run() {    println("dog running")  }
}
```

I want to achieve the most succinct JSON for network transmission, that is , `{"runnable":"H"}` for Horse and `{"runnable":"D"}` for Dog

**If I cannot modify the interface and implementations** , I want to serialize the interface/implementations to JSON , according to Kotlin's documentation , I have to write a  [custom serializer](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/custom_serializers.md) , and use `SerializersModule` to achieve the goal.

Suppose there are only `Horse` and `Dog` implementing `IRunnable` , This is what I've done :

```
class RunnableSerializer : KSerializer<IRunnable> {
  override val descriptor: SerialDescriptor
    get() = StringDescriptor.withName("runnable")


  override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, obj: IRunnable) {
    val stringValue = when (obj) {
      is Horse -> { "H" }
      is Dog -> { "D" }
      else -> { null }
    }
    stringValue?.also {
      encoder.encodeString(it)
    }
  }

  override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): IRunnable {
    return decoder.decodeString().let { value ->
      when(value) {
        "H" -> Horse()
        "D" -> Dog()
        else -> throw RuntimeException("invalid $value")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But when I try to transform a `Horse` to JSON ...

```
class RunnableTest {

  private val logger = KotlinLogging.logger { }

  @ImplicitReflectionSerializer
  @Test
  fun testJson() {
    val module1 = serializersModuleOf(IRunnable::class, RunnableSerializer())

    Json(context = module1).stringify(IRunnable::class.serializer(), Horse()).also {
      logger.info("json = {}", it)
    }
  }
}
```

It outputs error :

```
kotlinx.serialization.SerializationException: 
Can't locate argument-less serializer for class IRunnable. For generic classes, such as lists, please provide serializer explicitly.
```

How to achieve something like 
`{"runnable":"H"}` or `{"runnable":"D"}` in this case ?

Thanks.

environments :

```
<kotlin.version>1.3.60</kotlin.version>
<serialization.version>0.14.0</serialization.version>
```

updated , full error message :

```
kotlinx.serialization.SerializationException: Can't locate argument-less serializer for class IRunnable. For generic classes, such as lists, please provide serializer explicitly.

    at kotlinx.serialization.PlatformUtilsKt.serializer(PlatformUtils.kt:12)
    at RunnableTest.testJson(RunnableTest.kt:17)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
```

Comment: it seems that one/both of `Horse` & `Dog` classes have parameterized constructors(maybe optional but parameterized).

Comment: No... that's the full source code , no other constructors..

Comment: Is this the full error/stacktrace? If not can you add full trace?

Comment: Hi.this is the source code and test code. https://github.com/smallufo/kotlinPlay/tree/master/serialize/src. ...

Comment: I was asking for error's stack trace, since source is not big, just as you said before.

Comment: Make sure you have followed this [Guide line by Kotlin devs](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization)

Comment: I updated the full message , you can inspect into it. thanks.

Answer (score 9):

What you are trying to achieve is called polymorphic serialization, [which kotlinx.serialization supports](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/polymorphism.md). In short: it requires you to register all deriving types of `IRunnable` as polymorphic in the `SerialModule`. For your code it should look somewhat as follows:

```
val serialModule = SerializersModule {
    polymorphic(IRunnable::class) {
        Horse::class with HorseSerializer
        Dog::class with DogSerializer
    }
}
```

Currently, you only register `IRunnable`, which as the exception correctly indicates, cannot be initialized. How would you initialize an interface? You can't. Instead, you want to know which specific deriving type to initialize. This requires to embed type information within the JSON data, which is what polymorphic serialization does.

In addition, you do not necessarily have to implement a custom serializer. As per the documentation you link to, you can create [external serializers for library classes](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/custom_serializers.md#external-serializers-for-library-classes). The following might suffice, as the kotlinx.serialization compiler plugin will try to generate a suitable serializer for you, similar to if you were to add `@Serializable` on the class directly:

```
@Serializer(forClass = Horse::class)
object HorseSerializer {}

@Serializer(forClass = Dog::class)
object DogSerializer {}
```

Comment: Hi , I tried your code , but still not working ... code here : https://gist.github.com/smallufo/85632e827432a03e2da3f7d858d39460

Comment: I found the document means this situation : https://gist.github.com/smallufo/c47e641cae24252b610e5d581b6cff78 , that the interface must be inside a `@Serializable` container , in this example `Zoo` . Then it works ok . but that's not what I really want... I hope a simple {"runnable":"H"} and {"runnable":"D"} mapping

Comment: If you want to specify custom serialization (the simple example you provide is custom polymorphic serialization), you need to implement a custom serializer as you were attempting at first. You should then annotate your custom serializer with the `@Serializer(forClass) ` attribute, and specify `Serializable(with)` anywhere you want to do your custom serialization. I don't think the serial module is involved then.

Comment: Or, register as polymorphic as I specify in this answer, but associate your custom serializer for all deriving types, instead of the plugin-generated one per specific type.